# Spring boot consuming rest api in Gradle

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I'm completely new to Java and trying to consume a rest API with Spring Boot in Gradle, so far I've managed to make a very basic get request to display a message like below

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String printWelcome(ModelMap model) {
        model.addAttribute("message", "Hello");
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

Now, how to extend this get request to make HTTP requests consume an endpoint based on RestTemplate, assuming this is my endpoint that i want to consume like below:

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(); ResponseEntity response = restTemplate.getForEntity("http://aws.services.domain.com/country/id", String.class);
```

Finally, I want to achieve authorized HTTP GET requests by adding a token Bearer in the Authorization header.

Thank you for answers and suggestions in advance

Comment: What is the question? What are you expecting to happen, and what is actually happening?

Comment: @JayElston I want to make HTTP requests to the endpoint that's secured with a token, so how to use rest template properly and where I add authorization header?

Comment: ... and how is the question `gradle`-related?

Comment: @Turing85, apparently not an important relation, i'm just learning about Java, now I know it's just built automation tool like Maven :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add a header, you have to use `exchange` or `execute` method.

So, in your case:

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.set("Authorization", "Your Bearer Token");
HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(headers);
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
    url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class, param);
```

Comment: Thank you, by "url" you mean I should replace with endpoint I want to make requests to?

Comment: thanks, but I&#39;m still struggling without finding a proper way to make Oauth token authorized requests, can you provide an example or share a tutorial?

Comment: For example [here](https://gist.github.com/cjstehno/4fcc88f9266ed4ae268c)